# wpf button image runtime invisible

Tags: wpf

Can't figure out why in runtime image on button is not visible. At the same time in design mode it looks fine.
Also tried to remove Stretch, set Height and Width for image, change image to jpg/png, change Source to "ProjectName,component"
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `Stretch="Fill"`?

Comment: @Florian - Just tried - the same result - empty button with specified size. I'm newbie in wpf - maybe missed something obvious...

Comment: Did you set the png's Build Action to `Resource`?

Comment: Thank you. Set Build Actiona: Resource, Copy to Output: Do not copy. Didn't help...

Comment: Try just `/Resources/Button-Turn-Off-icon.jpg` as Source. Did work for me.

Comment: Thank you, I've already put an answer here. But your solution looks a bit simpler. Can you combine all your answers in one post I could mark it as answer to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When images were added to project resources Visual Studio set Build Action to None for such files...

1. Set `Build Action` to `Resource`
2. Change source to `/Resources/filename.png`
3. Set the size for the parent object
4. Set `Stretch` for image

See working snippet

```
<Button x:Name="BtName" Click="Bt_Click" Height="35" Width="35">
   <Image Source="/Resources/Button-Turn-Off-icon.png" Stretch="Fill" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Build Action to Resource, set always copy and add the image to the bin\debug (and release if you are using it) files. Some times VS doesn't bring it in and I don't know why but I had the same problem recently.

Comment: Thank you but I would like to store those images in exe file

Comment: Then after you do the above you need to turn them into resource files.